# how to handle mouse click in powershell

Tags: powershell, click, mouse

I have and text box in and I want to clear the text box when the mouse click is happen , I am using PrimalForms to use powershell with GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code to clear the text box on the click event handler. For example, clicking button1:

```
$handler_button1_Click={
    $textbox1.Text=''
}
```

Here's how to add the click event handler directly to button1 (without using PrimalForms):

```
$button1.add_Click( {$textbox1.Text=''})
```